# AAD Connect supported on Windows Server 2019

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is AAD Connect supported on Windows Server 2019? I was not able to find a statement on the documentation pages here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

You may have already seen this page but... It doesn't say it's not supported.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory/AAD-Connect-on-Server-2019/td-p/319311

Question:

> Has there been any announcement on when the AAD Connect tool will be supported on Server 2019? Can only see Windows Server 2019 Essentials mentioned in the release notes.

Answer:

> Well, it says that it's not supported in Windows Server 2019 Essentials, but it does not say it's not supported in Windows Server 2019...indeed it says it's supported on Windows Server 2012 R2 SP1 or later https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-prerequisites

Follow up:

> Thanks for the response, on the release notes it says it is supported for Windows server essentials from version 1.1.880.0.
>
> Added support for Windows Server Essentials 2019
> Would like to have seen something on the AAD connect release notes referencing Windows Server 2019 before advising the customer.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked - it would be good to have a clear statement form Microsoft which versions are actually supported